# How can I force the browser to use HTML 5

Tags: html

How can it be done?
I tried to write my html file like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

but it don't think that it forced html 5, in fact it didnt even work

Comment: This is probably basic lesson 1 stuff. @GeorgeWalt's answer is correct.

Comment: `in fact it didnt even work` -- how do you know?

Answer (score 5):

Try to add this before your html script:

```
<!doctype html>
```